# Difference between GoogleSignInApi and PLUS API for Android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin, google-plus-signin

Hi It is probably a silly question but I just can't find the difference between those two APIs. On seems to do exactly what the other does. I tried reading on the google developer website but It is just confusing.

I want to facilitate log in to my app by using Google+, but I just can't figure out what API should I use. I am only interested on the name of the user. I then create my own user database.

Thanksé

Comment: This really depends on scope. You should include the GoogleSignIn (auth) and Google+ (plus) libraries in your project. You can get the google plus by adding the Plus.Login "scope", and it will automatically make it google+ button. Then you want to get the sign in options to create an "instance" of the Plus user. It is kind of confusing, but not reading and understanding the APIs is a bad idea. Try to follow examples, and take it step by step.

Comment: Are you using gplus api just for the name of user ?

Comment: Well Yes i dont really need much for this app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the old Google-Sign Methods(before play services 8.3).
The best/easiest option now is to try out the new Google-Sign In with play services 8.3. The Google identity platform is completely revamped. It no longer has two separate API's.

Using the Google Sign in Options object you request the user's profile. The default sign in will get you users ID and basic profile. Include additional scopes(drive, google-plus) to GSO object to have more access.

Check out [new Google-Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start).

Also refer these posts from the official android developers blog to get more info.

[Android Developers Blog- Identity #1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/11/improvements-to-sign-in-with-google.html)

[Android Developers Blog- Identity #2](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/12/api-updates-for-sign-in-with-google.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are also below two improvements on GoogleSignInApi:

1. Better server authentication and authorization support:

   [Blog #3 - Using Google Sign-In with your server](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html)

   [Blog #4 - Using Credentials between your Server and Google Services](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/using-credentials-between-your-server.html)
2. No requirement for device level permission to get user email address. All data is backed up by OAuth scope: [GoogleSignInAccount.getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount.html#public-methods)